# Fitch system (exercise)

Tags: logic

I'm completing the Stanford's "Introduction to Logic" course, and I'm having issues with the following exercise:

"Consider a language with object constants a and b, binary function constant c, and unary relation constants m and p and q. The definitions for the relations are shown below. Relation m is true of a and only a. Relation p is true of a structured object if and only if it is a linear list (as defined in Chapter 7) with a top-level element that satisfies m. Relation q is true of a structured object if and only if there is an element anywhere in the structure that satisfies m.

Your job is to show that any object that satisfies p also satisfies q. Starting with the axioms, use Fitch with Structural Induction to prove ∀x.(p(x) ⇒ q(x)). Beware: The proof requires more than 50 steps (including the premises)."

I think I'm getting there, but I've been stuck in step 24 for days now.

[image]

How can I go on?
Thanks

Comment: Already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3700274/stuck-in-logic-exercise) yesterday. What are the benefit of copy-pasting the solution and re-posting it again ?

Comment: Hi Mauro. Thank you for your answer but it is not the same exercise. The conclusion I've to reach is the same but the premises I start with are all different. Could you please re open this question?

Comment: You should better use MathJax to format your question. It's hard to read.

Comment: Hi Aryadeva, I don't know how to use MathJax. I've edited the question as much as I could so it's more clear. (I've been given the 14 premises; from step 15 it's my creation).

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of the exercise.

Comment: As per the previous question, what is wrong with pushing the [Show Answer](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/problems/exercise_12_04.html) button ?

Comment: Sorry Mauro, I had not seen this. Thanks a lot!